# How can I remove the quotation mark and commas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a date in "12/5/24" format and I am trying to use it in a JavaScript function.

How can I use the date with no quotation marks and with commas?:

```
Date.UTC(12,5,24)
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
date = "12/5/24"
var = date.some_method  #=> 12,5,24
Date.UTC(var)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date_array = "12/5/24".split("/").collect(&:to_i)
Date.UTC(date_array[0], date_array[1], date_array[2])
```

Answer (score 3):

Write as below :

```
string =  "12/5/24"
Date.UTC(*string.split('/').map(&:to_i))
```

Answer (score 1):

All the `split` and `gsub` answers are "wrong", because they fit the anti-pattern "cause the bug, then fix the bug." (Yet they are not "completely wrong", because sometimes that anti-pattern is unfortunately the simplest option!)

Use `Time.parse(date).strftime('%m,%d,%y')`. That's why you have to escape each `y` token in a time template with a percent `%` - so you have a whole string to play with, and can put anything else in it. You could even put the rest of your Javascript in there.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.UTC( *"12/5/24".split('/') )`